# Getting all possible combination for [1,0] with length 3 [0,0,0] to [1,1,1]

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

```
    from itertools import combinations
   
     
def n_length_combo(arr, n):
     
    # using set to deal
    # with duplicates 
    return list(combinations(arr, n))
   
# Driver Function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = '01'
    n = 3
    print (n_length_combo([x for x in arr], n) )
```

##### Expected Output

[image]

wanted 3 combination of 0 and 1 .Tried with above example but it is not working

Comment: `list(product((0, 1), repeat=3))`?

Comment: Btw, with just `0` and `1` you can use `range(1 << 3)` and print numbers in binary. E.g. `[f"{i:03b}" for i in range(1 << 3)]`

Comment: Why does the expected output jump to `1 1 0`? Are you sure you're trying to get the combinations? Cause that output looks more like the product. Or maybe you're trying to get combinations *with replacement*? You can [edit] to clarify. Please include the *full* expected output as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Also for completeness, include the actual output. (I get `[]`.) For more tips, see [mre] and [ask].

Comment: BTW, there's a comment that says "using set to deal with duplicates", but there's no `set` involved here. What's up with that?

Comment: BTW, `[x for x in arr]` is unnecessary since all the combinatorics functions in `itertools` can take any iterable, including a string. But if you did need a list, it's simpler to write `list(arr)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), not a combination or permutation of `[0, 1]`. For that, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```py
from itertools import product

items = [0, 1]

for item in product(items, repeat=3):
    print(item)
```

This produces the output you're looking for (albeit in a slightly different order):

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```